# How to memset() memory to a certain pattern instead of a single byte?

Tags: c, memory, design-patterns, memset

I need to write a repeating pattern to memory (e.g. `0x11223344`), so that the whole memory looks like (in hex):

```
1122334411223344112233441122334411223344112233441122334411223344...
```

I can't figure out how to do it with `memset()` because it takes only a single byte, not 4 bytes.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An efficient way would be to cast the pointer to a pointer of the needed size in bytes (e.g. `uint32_t` for 4 bytes) and fill with integers. It's a little ugly though.

```
char buf[256] = { 0, };
uint32_t * p = (uint32_t *) buf, i;

for (i = 0; i < sizeof(buf) / sizeof(* p); i++) {
    p[i] = 0x11223344;
}
```

Not tested!

Comment: The one thing to be aware of is that `buf` might not satisfy the alignment requirements for a `uint32_t` on your platform.  If `buf` is the result of a `malloc`, you don't need to worry about this, but if it's (say) passed in as an argument by code you don't control, you'll need to check the alignment before you write to it in this fashion, or else this will result in invalid accesses on some platforms.

Comment: Another thing to watch for may be endianness, if this is run on a little endian computer and the filling and reading are done using types with different sizes (ie. filling with int but reading with char)

Comment: This is not very efficient; using `memmove()` as in my example is much, much faster because it uses special assembler ops and hand-optimized code.

Comment: You can still optimzed the code. For example you can use pointer arithmetic instead of the loop variable. I chose the example above to make the actual point of it clearer.

Comment: @Aaron Digulla: that claim depends on a lot of things: for small buffers, for example, you're going to get slaughtered by function call overhead making repeated small calls to `memmove( )`.  For "typical" buffers, your solution will probably be faster on most platforms with a well-optimized library, but for truly huge buffers, your solution will asymptotically take twice as many page faults and be very nearly 2x slower on most platforms.

Comment: @Stephen: It's simple to limit the block size to a few pages. And for small buffers, you can use optimize with the loop above.

Comment: @Aaron: Of course, but the code you posted in your answer doesn't do those things, and so the claim that it is "much, much faster" can't be justified without some additional assumptions.  If one is willing to trade complexity for performance, one would either use a platform-specific API like `memset_pattern4( )` or write a dedicated implementation themselves.

Comment: As far as I can tell the code contains UB in general case (not this snippet alone - other then before mentioned alignment) - the `buf` can be accessed as something else then `char` or `uint32_t` violating strict pointer aliasing rule - so if OP wanted to fill array of `float`s (s)he would run into UB.

Answer (score 9):

On OS X, one uses `memset_pattern4( )` for this; I would expect other platforms to have similar APIs.

I don't know of a simple portable solution, other than just filling in the buffer with a loop (which is pretty darn simple).

Comment: I forgot I could use loop. Thanks for reminding. Trying it with loop now.

Answer (score 6):

Recursively copy the memory, using the area which you already filled as a template per iteration O(log(N)):

```
int fillLen = ...;
int blockSize = 4; // Size of your pattern

memmove(dest, srcPattern, blockSize);
char * start = dest;
char * current = dest + blockSize;
char * end = start + fillLen;
while(current + blockSize < end) {
    memmove(current, start, blockSize);
    current += blockSize;
    blockSize *= 2;
}
// fill the rest
memmove(current, start, (int)end-current);
```

---

What I mean with O(log(N)) is that the runtime will be much faster than if you fill the memory manually since `memmove()` usually uses special, hand-optimized assembler loops that are blazing fast.

Comment: It's O(log(n)) calls to `memmove`; the actual complexity is still O(n).

Answer (score 6):

If your pattern fits in a `wchar_t`, you can use `wmemset()` as you would have used `memset()`.

Answer (score 2):

You could set up the sequence somewhere then copy it using [`memcpy()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/memcpy/) to where you need it.

Comment: `memset` can store only single-byte patterns, not a 4-byte int like that

Answer (score 2):

Well, the normal method of doing that is to manually setup the first four bytes, and then `memcpy(ptr+4, ptr, len -4)`

This copies the first four bytes into the second four bytes, then copies the second four bytes into the third, and so on.

Note, that this "usually" works, but is not guarenteed to, depending on your CPU architecture, and your C run-time library.

Comment: The behavior of `memcpy` is undefined if the source and destination buffers overlap.  This will probably work on some platforms, but it will certainly not work on many others.

Comment: This will overwrite the first four bytes with whatever is in the second four bytes. Further, `memcpy` should not be used with overlapping ranges.

Comment: Are you commenting on my original or editted message.  memcpy is (dest, src, len), which I have correct now. (I had it backward initially, but I though I had it fixed before your comment)

Comment: I was commenting on the original -- see that you fixed the order now. (I'd remove the downvote but you'd need to edit to unlock it)

Comment: Saying that this "usually" works is a little misleading; I expect this to fail for sufficiently large buffers on any modern platform that has a 64-bit or wider load/store path and a reasonably optimized `memcpy` implementation, and to fail on many platforms with a 32-bit wide load/store path as well.

Comment: IF you are just doing this for 4 bytes, you'd be better off speed wise with a straight *iPtr++ = dwordValue than a call to memcpy. memcpy is only faster once you get above N bytes. N being more than 4. Can't remember the value, but did some tests on it a few years back.

Comment: @STephen K: That really depends on the compiler/library.  Many modern compilers will automatically inline the memcpy, so you'd be doing explicitly merely what the compiler would be doing implicitly.

Comment: @James Curran. I was thinking of the Microsoft implementation. Last time I looked its in assembler as a discrete non-inlineable function. Even if it was inline-able, my statement would still stand correct. Take a look at the code. The first things it does it determine if the copy is DWORD aligned and if not it copies individual bytes until it is DWORD aligned then does a DWORD mov instruction with a repeat instruction directive. Not looked at the x64 implementation but wouldn't be at all surprised to find extra code in there to handle QWORD copying (with extra delay due to extra comparisons)

Comment: @Stephen: `memcpy` is listed among the functions MSC++ will inline (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tzkfha43(v=VS.71).aspx).  I don't recall when they started doing that, but I'm pretty sure it goes back to the mid-90's, at least.

Comment: @James. memcpy inlining is supported when memcpy is defined as an instrinsic (I didn't know that, thank you). intrinsic is something MS added when they started supporting x64 (and as a by product they removed inline assembler :-(), so at a guess this goes back to VS2005. Anyway, take a look at the memcpy implementation, it spends so much time up front working out what to do that for a small number of bytes you are faster copying yourself. We did the timings and added in a check so that we only call memcpy for a number of bytes exceeding N (which I can't remember what N is).

Answer (score 2):

Standard C library has no such function. But memset is usually implemented as an unrolled loop to minimize branching and condition checking:

```
static INLINE void memset4(uint32_t *RESTRICT p, uint32_t val, int len) {
  uint32_t *end = p + (len&~0x1f); //round down to nearest multiple of 32
  while (p != end) { //copy 32 times
    p[ 0] = val;
    p[ 1] = val;
    p[ 2] = val;
    p[ 3] = val;
    p[ 4] = val;
    p[ 5] = val;
    p[ 6] = val;
    p[ 7] = val;
    p[ 8] = val;
    p[ 9] = val;
    p[10] = val;
    p[11] = val;
    p[12] = val;
    p[13] = val;
    p[14] = val;
    p[15] = val;
    p[16] = val;
    p[17] = val;
    p[18] = val;
    p[19] = val;
    p[20] = val;
    p[21] = val;
    p[22] = val;
    p[23] = val;
    p[24] = val;
    p[25] = val;
    p[26] = val;
    p[27] = val;
    p[28] = val;
    p[29] = val;
    p[30] = val;
    p[31] = val;
    p += 32;
  }
  end += len&0x1f; //remained
  while (p != end) *p++ = val; //copy remaining bytes
}
```

Good compiler will likely use some CPU specific instructions to optimize it further (like i.e. use SSE 128-bit store), but even without optimizations, it should be as fast as a library memset, because such simple loops are memory access bound.

Answer (score 0):

I was thinking about this today when I had to duplicate a complex scalar across a memory aligned array in order to use Volk to perform SIMD multiplication. I see the solutions above but I don't know enough about compilers to say what will and won't be optimized. I plan to benchmark a few of these suggestions, but the solution that occurred to me is:

```
inline void duplicate_32fc(lv_32fc_t *out, lv_32fc_t in, int size) {

    int n = 1;
    int last_n;

    if (n < 1)
        return;

    //Copy the first one
    out[0] = in;

    //Double the size of the copy for each copy
    while (n*2 <= size) {
        memcpy(&out[n], out, n * sizeof(lv_32fc_t));
        last_n = n;
        n = n * 2;
    }

    //Copy the tail
    if (last_n < size) {
        memcpy(&out[last_n], out, (size - last_n) * sizeof(lv_32fc_t));
    }
}
```

Each iteration copies all of the previous copies to the new space so I think it is O(log(n)), no?